# Datepicker(Jquery) in Listview (asp.net), Code Behind(vb.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox in a listview, it receives its input from DatePicker(Jquery). Now I have to validate the date/input from that textbox.
This how the logic of my code is:
A user will select through Radio button which one she chooses to purchase.
If the user selects [Mango], a textbox for the date will appear as well as the calendar icon for datepicker jquery. Now the user will select the date for [Effective Date]. The Datepicker does that perfectly but I don't know how to validate if the user chooses the right date, since it should be within the date range provided from the database. For example, the Mango season, the effective date should only starts from May 2023 onwards, if the user choose April 13, 2023, it will trigger a warning that she should choose another date.

I thought I tried when the textbox changed it's value, but this will only trigger when the user click enter on the keyboard. I need to validate the input once the datepicker inputs the value on textbox. How do I do that please? I'm using vb.net on codebehind.

Part of the markup:

```
    <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
          <%# CheckNull(Eval("EFF_DATE"))%>
          <ASP:Textbox runat="server" ID="dtEffectiveDate" CssClass="dateSelector"
                                    MonitorChanges="true" 
                    OnTextChanged="dtEffectiveDate_TextChanged" />                                   
                                
    </td>
```

Part of the script:

```
$("<%=listView.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
    $('.dateSelector').datepicker();
});
```

For Sample purposes:
[image: ListView Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear why you don't just use TextMode="date" (you don't need the jQuery date picker).

However, be this this any text box?

You can add/have/set a ontextchanged event. However, to have it "auto" trigger when it changes? You need to add this:

```
                <asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="dtEffectiveDate" 
                    CssClass="dateSelector"
                    MonitorChanges="true"
                    OnTextChanged="dtEffectiveDate_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"            
                    />
```

I also have no idea what "MonitorChanges" is here???

So, code behind for above can now be:

```
Protected Sub dtEffectiveDate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim dtEffctive As TextBox = sender
    Dim lvRow As ListViewItem = dtEffctive.NamingContainer

    Dim txtTree As Label = lvRow.FindControl("lblTree")

    ' code here to get the data in question


End Sub
```

So above shows how to pick up the current row - get other control values from the current row that trigger the changed event.

But, you will need the autopostback = true, and this is required for any text box that you want to "post-back" the page.

If you don't post-back the page (with autopost-back = true), then upon submit, the ontext changed event will fire, but that probably not what you are looking for.

So, to trigger the event(s) for a textbox, unlike a button, you have to add the autopostback = "true" to the text box.

Comment: Yes, autopostback is what I'm missing. Yes I don't want the [Enter] /Down Keypress to trigger the validation, I want it automatic. Thanks again for helping me.